# .click function in not working on a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, label

I am having dynamically creating remove label. All have same class but different Ids. I want to get the id when I click a label. I used `$(.class).click` function but it didn't work. I can't use `onclick` function because `$(this).attr('id')` is not working in IE 8.

Please give me a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.click doesn't work on elements that are created later dynamically.
therefore use .live()

```
$('.class').live('click', function(){ alert(this.id); });
```

Update:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers.

The above example using .on()

```
$('body').on('click','.class',function(){ alert(this.id); });
```

Comment: Still a useful answer two years later.

Comment: @user1821973 except live is deprecated since jQuery 1.7. .on() should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".class").click(function(){alert(this.id)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, using the event argument that gets passed to the click handler function instead of `this`.

```
$('label.foo').click(function(event) {console.log($(event.target).attr('id'))});
```